# D365FO x++ Deleting a File from SharePoint folder by SharePointHelper class

Tags: sharepoint, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I need to delete a file from sharepoint by a D365FO x++ runbase job.
I get the proxy succesfully by the method SharePointHelper::CreateProxy
but when I use it to delete the file the method DeleteFile doesn't work.
I think the problem is the uri.
I build the uri in this way:

uri = new System.Uri("https://" + host  + "/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/" + site + "/" + folderPath + "/" + fileName + "')");
myProxy.DeleteFile(uri);

Could please anyone help me with this?

Comment: Store the URI in a variable first, examine it, post what it is (anonymizing business info).

Comment: Hi , I've solved the problem. This is the correct format for the uri: https://my_host/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/my_site/my_folder/file_name'). Anyway thanks for the support. Regards Daniele